# how to export a graph to svg/graphml

Tags: java, jgraphx

I am little bit stuck on how to export graphs to svg or graphml. Neither the api, examples or threads on forum.jgraph.com did help me until now.

I need to export graphs to both svg and graphml. I got svg to display the nodes and edges even with the correct layout, but I'm missing information like names of nodes and assigned colors.

With graphml I have no clue yet how to get the correct xml code to even display a functioning graph.

Is there any guideline/workflow somewhere which might help me with export in JGraphX?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Chris

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to save your graph you have to call mxCellRendered to render your graph to a mxicanvas from which you get your Document (dom document). 
From the Renderer it goes like this: 
mxGraph.drawCell() -> mxGraph.drawState() -> mxICanvas.drawCell() -> mxICanvas.drawShape() 
mxICanvas knows only the cell's geometry and style.

I wanted the cell id attribute added in the svg file as well, so I did the following

1. extended the mxGraph to override the drawCell() in order to add the cell id in the style of the cell, and
2. extended the mxSvgCanvas for adding the id attribute for the shapes that interested me

The function to save as svg graph goes like:

```
// use the extended svg canvas, where the cell id is added as attribute
public void createSVG(mxGraphExtended g) {
  String filename = "\home\koula\graph.svg";
  mxSvgCanvasExtended canvas = (mxSvgCanvasExtended) mxCellRenderer.drawCells(
    g, null, 1, null, new CanvasFactory() {
    public mxICanvas createCanvas(int width, int height) {
        mxSvgCanvasExtended canvas = new mxSvgCanvasExtended(mxDomUtils
            .createSvgDocument(width, height));
            canvas.setEmbedded(true);
            return canvas;
        } 
    });
  try {
    mxUtils.writeFile(mxXmlUtils.getXml(canvas.getDocument()), filename);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
```

The overriden drawCell():

```
public class mxGraphExtended extends mxGraph {

    @Override
    public void drawCell(mxICanvas canvas, Object cell) {
        // add the cell's id as a style attribute
        // cause canvas only get the style and geometry
        mxCellState state = this.getView().getState(cell);
        state.getStyle().put("cellid", ((mxCell)cell).getId());

        super.drawCell(canvas, cell);
    }
}
```

The overridden drawShape() goes like:

```
public class mxSvgCanvasExtended extends mxSvgCanvas {

    //... have coppied only the related code

    @Override
    public Element drawShape(int x, int y, int w, int h, 
        Map<String, Object> style)
    {
         //... 

         // Draws the shape
         String shape = mxUtils.getString(style, mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE, "");
         String cellid = mxUtils.getString(style, "cellid", "");
         Element elem = null;
         // ... 

        // e.g. if image, add the cell id 
        if (shape.equals(mxConstants.SHAPE_IMAGE)) {
            String img = getImageForStyle(style);
            if (img != null) {
                // Vertical and horizontal image flipping
                boolean flipH = mxUtils.isTrue(style, 
                    mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE_FLIPH, false);
                boolean flipV = mxUtils.isTrue(style, 
                    mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE_FLIPV, false);
                elem = createImageElement(x, y, w, h, img,
                    PRESERVE_IMAGE_ASPECT, flipH, flipV, isEmbedded());
                /* so here we are */ 
                // add the cell id atribute 
                if(!cellid.equals("")) {
                    elem.setAttribute("id", cellid);
                }
            }
        } else if (shape.equals(mxConstants.SHAPE_LINE))
            // ... 
        }// end drawShape

     } // end class
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, do you mind looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179673/drawio-mxgraph-using-xmltosvg-loses-shapes-information

Looks like my SVG loses shapes information after conversion