# Converting XML to SVG in mxGraph javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, mxgraph

I am trying to convert mxGraph's XML graph into SVG using JavaScript. Having XML string, I need to parse it into an SVG for distributing further to the html. 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179673/drawio-mxgraph-using-xmltosvg-loses-shapes-information) shows exactly what I need to do with the [solution implemented in Java](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/java/examples/com/mxgraph/examples/Xml2Svg.java) . I can parse XML into graph and cannot render graph into SVG, cannot  seem to find method that would be equivalent to drawCells() method in mxCellRenderer.js.

Would anyone be able to help on converting XML to SVG using JavaScript only (available mxGraph library)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me:

data - represents mxGraphModel XML

```
var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(data); // parse XML into document
var graph = new Graph(container, null, null, null, null); // create Graph instance, container is an HTML element where the SVG will be exported
var outputSvg = graph.getSvg("#FFFFFF", 1, null, null, true, null, null);
```

The final output is SVG object that can be included in HTML document:

```
document.getElementById('divForSvg').appendChild(outputSvg );
```

Check Graph.js an its getSvg() method for the details.

Comment: where have you used the existing XML to make the Graph .??

Answer (score 0):

Search for the `setGraphXml` function that is in the graphEditor example of mxGraph (in Editor.js)

This will read the xml and renders it on the graph